# How to pass attributes in Serializer not in model in Rails (ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, serialization

I am building a Rails backend that has `Users`, `Sightings` and `Comments`. The model`Comment` joins `Sighting` and `User`. I would like to pass the user's name or username along with the user_id which is an attribute of join table `Comments` in `CommentSerializer` to my front-end.

I can access this data using Active Record or Ruby methods but how do actually make this an attribute to be passed through Serializer?

Here's my `CommentSerializer` file:

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :body, :likes, :user_id

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :sighting
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your attributes :user_name for example and then add

> `def user_name
>        object.user.name
>   end`

in your CommentSerializer class

Comment: Thanks for the response and so nice to no I can just do some sweet Ruby methods right in the Serializer. I added a migration file to `comments` table with `user_name` so it's an attribute now. I put the code you gave above in the `CommentSerializer` class but get ``` NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for 42:Integer):
  
app/serializers/comment_serializer.rb:10:in `user_name' ```

Comment: I ended up drilling down to the information by using this method to find the relationship. ``` def user_name
     User.all.find { |f| f.id == object.user_id }.username 
  end ```

Comment: This is not a rails way. You can add in comment model code like this `belongs_to :user`. See this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference. After this, you can use `comment.user` method to get object of your user

Comment: FYI, you can optimize your user searching like this: `User.find_by(id: object.user_id)`. In your case, you load all users and search needed user by ruby. In my case, User is found by one SQL request.

Comment: I do have model relationship but can't get it to work. I'll try again and see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

So I had good luck with this method in my Serializer file to pass down this attribute:

```
  def user_name
 User.all.find { |f| f.id == object.user_id }.username
```

end